# Doctrine.. Proper way to map values created in query, to entity class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Say I have a database table **uploads** that has **id, user_id, upload, createdDate** and a entity class that reflects the user table.

I then have a query that would be something like.

```
SELECT u.id, 
  u.name, 
  u.createdDate,
  u.user_id,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM uploads
   WHERE user_id in 
       (SELECT id from uploads
        WHERE user_id = :id) 
    AND createdDate BETWEEN date_sub(NOW(),interval 1 day) 
    AND date_sub(NOW(),interval 0 day)) as countLastDayUploads
FROM uploads as u
WHERE u.user_id = :id
```

This would return an extra value, **countLastDayUploads**, which is not reflected in the schema .  ***Two questions here.***  Should countLastDayUploads be stored in the upload entity class without annotation?  I'm thinking yes...

Second how would I write this query using the Symfony2 doctrine query builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add it to the entity leaving out the annotation.  The doctrine should map the results to the object.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.id, 
  u.name, 
  u.createdDate,
  u.user_id,
  count(*) as count
FROM uploads as u
WHERE 
    u.user_id = :id
  AND 
    createdDate > (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY u.user_id
```

if i understand you right - this code must work five

and

`id`, `user_id`, `upload`, `createdDate` - wrong names

`id`, `userId`, `upload`, `createdDate` - better, but wrong

`id`, `user_id`, `upload`, `created_date` - good

This is mysql standards.

Comment: I was going to use count for the example then changed mind when I had a question about best way to write it.  Currently it's just sitting as a createQuery().  I didn't know if that was best way.  Agreed on naming convention.  So is it best to keep a count variable in the uploads entity?

Comment: For this db structure for one/current user maybe. But if upload boolean, thats wrong if upload store upload id, than upload_id better. And with time this table will have a big size. You need 2 table, first in memory and second normal. Ang agregate data with 1 hour interval from memory table